# Can't get Realtek ALC1150 to work on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, realtek, soundcard, ubuntu-drivers

I am using an ASUS All Series/X99-A, BIOS 4101 07/10/2019.

The soundcard in question is the Motherboard builtin.

This question seems at first like a repeat of [this question for 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842294/how-to-fix-wrong-audio-profile-on-skylake-realtek-alc1150) but the accepted answer was that kernel 4.10 would fix the issue. However I'm at kernel 5.4.0 and the issue persists.

I have already installed+reinstalled pulseaudio and all the alsa config files. I have already followed many recipes and added all these options (once each) to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1 bdl_pos_adj=0,-1
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1 model=auto 
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=1 model=auto
```

in every possible combination. One combination (forgot which) actually worked for a couple of months but then it suddenly stopped working.

I can see the card in the alsa mixer

[image]

but it does not show up in pulseaudio volume control.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What can I possibly try? Should I just take the L at this point?

Thank you!

```
$ lspci -vv 
...
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 33
        NUMA node: 0
        Region 0: Memory at 383ffff10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 00000000fee08000  Data: 4022
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v1) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
                        ExtTag- RBE- FLReset+
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop- FLReset-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ dmesg | grep 00:1b.0
[    2.306391] pci 0000:00:1b.0: [8086:8d20] type 00 class 0x040300
[    2.306413] pci 0000:00:1b.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x383ffff10000-0x383ffff13fff 64bit]
[    2.306491] pci 0000:00:1b.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    6.460094] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[    6.460126] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input16
[    6.460156] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
[    6.460184] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input18
[    6.460214] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input19
[    6.460241] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input20
[    6.460268] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input21
```

```
$ dmesg | grep snd_hda
[    6.404949] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    6.445157] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC1150: SKU not ready 0x00000000
[    6.445660] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC1150: line_outs=3 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    6.445661] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.445662] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    6.445663] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    6.445663] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x11/0x1e
[    6.445664] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    6.445665] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    6.445666] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    6.445666] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[   19.176070] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 26
[ 1748.151754] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 4
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason alsa+pulseaudio only work after I reload alsa completely after boot.

```
$ sudo alsa force-reload
Terminating processes: 1368.
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-usb-audio snd-hda-core snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-pcm snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-usb-audio snd-hda-core snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-usb-audio snd-hda-core snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-pcm snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

After that the built-in audio comes up in pavucontrol

[image]

However I have to do this every time the computer reloads.

Some other user online has suggested to remove timidity in case one reader wants to try but it did not work for me.

```bash
$ sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

It is amazing that this is 2023 and I still have to do this on a Linux desktop.

Comment: Try another distro (Manjaro) and check if works there. A Test with a live USB should verify if it's a Linux or a Distro problem

Comment: @kanehekili I have to use Ubuntu for professional reasons. Still, is there any reason why Ubuntu would be intrinsically inferior to Manjaro?

Comment: Not inferior, but different. Manjaro is based on Arch Linux, has different (newer)kernels and libraries. Consider it as "glance into future". Besides their pipewire integration is better than Ubutuntus. (pipewire is the successor of pulseaudio, which in fact you're using). So testing it could narrow down the problem. I do not want you to switch - just help to fix your problem on Ubuntu